# Fluent Inteface for Message Sender

Tags: java, fluent

I would like to create fluent API for message sender. Lets take simple example.

```java
messageSender.newMessage()
    .withSomeField("some value")
    .withAnotherField("some value")
.publish();
```

I have clases `messagePublisher` and `message`. `messagePublisher` has method `publish(message)`. How I can wrap this all together to achieve the fluent way as described above?

I have came up with solution where I have class 'messageSender' which contains instance of 'messagePublisher' and use it to publish message. When I call `messageSender.newMessage()` it will return `messageBuilder` but this `messageBuilder` needs to have reference to messageSender, so I am than able to call the publish() method. I do not like that `messageBuilder` has reverence to `messageSender` but I am not sure how to do it differently.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: I may be missing something, but wouldn't you also have a plain Java getter/setter class called `Message`?  Your `MessageCreator` class would create a `Message` instance and your `MessagePublisher` class would consume and process a `Message` instance.  Some other controlling class would create an instance of `MessageCreator` and `MessagePublisher`.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but I would like to have it fluent so one method follows another without interruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inner class for MessageSender:

**MessageSender.java:**

```java
public class MessageSender {
  private MessagePublisher messagePublisher;
  public void setPublisher(MessagePublisher publisher) {
    this.messagePublisher = publisher;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
    messageSender.setPublisher(new MessagePublisher());
    messageSender.newMessage()
      .withDestination("DEST")
      .withMsg("message")
      .publish();
  }

  public MessageBuilder newMessage() {
    return new MessageBuilder();
  }

  class MessageBuilder {
    private Message message = new Message();

    public MessageBuilder withMsg(String msg) {
      message.setMsg(msg);
      return this;
    }

    public MessageBuilder withDestination(String destination) {
      message.setDestination(destination);
      return this;
    }

    public void publish() {
      messagePublisher.publish(message);
    }
  }
}
```

**MessagePublisher.java:**

```java
public class MessagePublisher {
  public void publish(Message message) {
    System.out.println(
      String.format(
        "Message to be sent: Msg=%s, Dest=%s", 
        message.getMsg(),
        message.getDestination()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Message.java:**

```java
public class Message {
  private String msg;
  private String destination;

  public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
  }

  public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
  }

  public String getMsg() {return this.msg;}
  public String getDestination() {return this.destination;}
}
```

Comment: also if u dont want to create builder by yourself you can use some trick with lombok, check on my git: https://github.com/fkzwd/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/src/main/java/com/vk/dwzkf/stackoverflow/question_77230554

Comment: I like this more than my original design,  thx.

Comment: @JakubZnamenáček  can you please tag my answer as correct? :)

Comment: I upvoted your response, will accept it in case there will not be better solution.